# Same logger to log in multiple destinations?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

How can I have one logger, which I get with `GetLogger()` method, logging to file AND rich text box at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use an IoC container.  Simply define an interface and then define your logger classes based on that interface.  They can then be created or injected into your other classes as needed.

Comment: Is this answer in `NLog` context?

Comment: I don't know anything about NLog context.  I usually use Castle Windsor, but you can also use any of these:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx

Comment: Please check the tag, my question is related to `NLog`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that last tag.  Please disregard my answer.

Answer (score 0):

your nlog configuration defines rules and targets independent from each other. Your requirement is to have 2 targets, a file logger and some other logger that displays your log entries in a text box. You would just add two rules to your nlog configuration to direct your log entries to those two targets.

this would be an example nlog.config that logs all logging entries to two different targets. You can set different minLevels for the individual logging rules. The first target is a simple file logger, the other target is a [MethodCall](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/MethodCall-target) target that calls a static method with the log parameters. See the [nlog documentation](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Targets) for all available targets and further documentation.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
   <configSections>
     <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
  <nlog>
    <targets>
      <target name="toFile" type="File" 
          layout="${longdate} ${level} [${threadid}] - ${callsite}: ${message} ${onexception:${newline}Ausnahme\:${exception:format=tostring}}" 
          fileName="${basedir}/log.txt"
          archiveFileName="${basedir}/log.{#####}.txt"
          archiveAboveSize="1024000"
          archiveNumbering="Sequence"
          concurrentWrites="true"
          keepFileOpen="false"
          maxArchiveFiles="3"
          />

      <target xsi:type="MethodCall"
         name="toRichTextBox"
         methodName="String"
         className="String">
         <parameter layout="Layout" name="String" type="System.Type"/><!-- repeated -->
      </target>

    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="toFile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="toRichTextBox" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: How in the code I could use single `logger.Debug(...)` for example, to have it log to both targets? Assuming I already have in the code lots of Debug messages which are writing to file target and I want to add also second target, without modifying all `logger.Debug` lines?

Comment: yup, that should work. You can use logger rules to log only messages from specific classes or namespaces (that is done in the "name" attribute, "*" in my example) to different targets, but you can also just forward all log entries to all targets if you like.

Comment: Could you please update your sample config with an example?

Comment: the config already contains both targets and rules. Do you mean the receiving class for the MethodCall target?

Comment: Having 2 targets, how I specify rules to forward to all targets? I don't need specific namespace or classes, just all is good enough. In the code I use `LogManager.GetLogger("toMultipleTargets")` and give all targets with same name?

Comment: you just create two rules, one for each target. Each rule forwards your logs to one target.

Comment: Not really. I had to create one rule like this, which solved the issue `<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="mmm,fff" />`.

Comment: that would work too, but you wouldn't be able to define different minLevels for your targets, for instance debug in a log file and info for your text box.